# Identify class(control name) of Mobile Element (Android/iOS) programmatically at runtime in Appium?

Tags: appium, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I am using Appium Mobile Driver. I want to identify platform specific class name (Control) of Mobile Element (For Android - Text View, Edit Text, Radio Button etc)

`MobileElement.getClass()` just returns the generic class name `io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement`.

Although Android's UIAutomatorViewer exposes '`class'` property but that is not 
accessible programmatically with Appium using `MobileElement.getAttribute("class")`. I suspect that Appium is hiding that property (I haven't tried directly using UiAutomator).

Does anyone have a clue?

Also any other way by which we can find out the class name programmatically using Appium or Do I need to use UiAutomator?

Comment: if you check out the inspector, the "class" attribute is actually called "type". So try `MobileElement.getAttribute("type")`

Comment: @econoMichael. Which inspector you are talking about?  Both Android's own UIAutomatorViewer and Appium's inspector show the "class" (and not the "type") attribute which is inaccessible programmatically in Appium. Both getAttribute("class") and  getAttribute("type") throw "NoSuchElementException"

Comment: hm is it a hybrid app? sounds like it's using webview. using appium inspector, the elements on my native app all have attribute "type" but not "class"

Comment: No its not hybrid app. Its completely native app. I am not using webview at all. Its strange that how can you see attribute type using appium inspector